# Relationship between the eigenvalues of a Laplacian matrix and the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian of a graph for Max-Cut

Tags: linear-algebra, hamiltonian

**Is there a relationship between the eigenvalues of a Laplacian matrix of a graph and the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian for Max-Cut?**

It is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005676/max-cut-form-of-graph-laplacian), that Max-Cut can be written as a maximization problem involving the graph Laplacian:

$$\underset{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}{\max} x^T L x, \quad x_i \in \{-1,1\},\quad i=1,...,n\tag{1}\,.$$

The *Laplacian matrix* is defined as:
$L=D-A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph.

The formulation is equivalent to maximizing- $$C(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{i,j} \omega_{ij} \cdot x_i(1-x_j), \quad x \in \{-1,1\}^n\tag{2}\,.$$

From this, the Hamiltonian can be constructed, with the assignment: $x_i \rightarrow (1-Z_i)/2$, where $Z_i$ is the Pauli-Z operator. The Hamiltonian becomes (see [this](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/optimization/tutorials/06_examples_max_cut_and_tsp.html)):

$$H=\sum\limits_{i<j}\omega_{ij}Z_iZ_j\,,\tag{3}$$ with some constant offset: $$cst = \sum\limits_{i<j}\omega_{ij}/2\,.\tag{4}$$

There are several results known for the eigenspectrum of the Laplacian of a graph, such as *Cheeger's inequality*. Is there some relation to the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian? Is there anything that can be followed for the *spectral gap* of the Hamiltonian?